# Truncating Text To Full Words Based On Character Limit - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, word-count, texttrimming, character-limit

I'm working with some data (DataSet#1) which has a text field truncated using some unconventional logic:

- If "Service Type Description" is > 60 Characters, Trim the name down to < 60 characters, but only **full** words

My problem is that I need to format some other data (DataSet#2) in excel to match this logic which is being applied on the back-end on our reporting server (outside my control). No one can seem to find a list of all the potential truncated descriptions either.

Dataset#1 is live and can be re-pulled with updated data at any time, so I need to create a template that allows me to pull in information from the list in DataSet#2 (which currently has the full length descriptions) into any copy of Dataset#1 based on the trimmed Service Type Description in DataSet#1.

---

Example:
The following is the full product name, and the product name in my DataSet#2:

- "FNMA 1025 Small Residential Income Property Appraisal & FNMA 216 Addendum" (73 characters, including spaces)

Simply trimming this text to be <60 characters (59) would yield:

- "FNMA 1025 Small Residential Income Property Appraisal & FNM"

However, this same product, in the main data (DataSet#1) is named as follows:

- "FNMA 1025 Small Residential Income Property Appraisal & " (56 characters, 8 "words", including &)

The logic on the back-end for DataSet#1 has trimmed the full product name to under 60 characters, but retains only full words (removes the "FNM" partial word).

---

Ideally I have to be able to take a list that has the full description name - and apply logic in Excel (or VBA) that will yield the same result as the trimmed data from the other dataset - which then allows me to pull information from dataset #2 (full product names) into dataset#1 based on the service type description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like so

```
Function truncate_string(strInput As String, Optional lngChars As Long = 60)

Dim lngCharInstance As Long


lngCharInstance = Len(strInput)

While lngCharInstance > lngChars 
   lngCharInstance = InStrRev(strInput, " ", _
                    IIf(lngCharInstance >= Len(strInput), _
                    Len(strInput), lngCharInstance - 1))
Wend

truncate_string = Mid(strInput, 1, lngCharInstance)

End Function
```

This would be called like so

`truncate_string("FNMA 1025 Small Residential Income Property Appraisal & FNMA 216 Addendum")`

and would return as follows

`FNMA 1025 Small Residential Income Property Appraisal &`

or like so for, 30 chars for example

`truncate_string("FNMA 1025 Small Residential Income Property Appraisal & FNMA 216 Addendum",30)`

which gives

`FNMA 1025 Small Residential`

Hope this helps, as there is a loop in there, i'd look at the possibilities of any potential for infinite loops.

Comment: Thank you - this worked for exactly what I needed and the optional # of characters variable is helpful because it turned out there are other field truncated at different lengths in the same dataset. Depending on implementation need, I called this function within a conditional IF statement - to avoid the function running should it encounter a blank value or value larger than the database field max (200 char - meaning it wouldn't be a field that needed to be truncated:
`=IF(OR(LEN(A2)>200,LEN(A2)<1,A2=""), truncate_string(A2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions for this.

```
Option Explicit
Function trimLength(S As String, Optional Length As Long = 60) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim sPat As String

sPat = "^.{1," & Length - 1 & "}(?=\s|$)"

If Len(S) > 60 Then
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Pattern = sPat
        .MultiLine = True
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
            trimLength = MC(0)
    End With
Else
    trimLength = S
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Note that, in accord with your question, we subtract one from the desired length.

*Explanation of the Regex*

### Trim Length to Whole Word

```
^.{1,59}(?=\s|$)
```

Options: ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNFCB.png) `^`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.{1,59}`

  - [Between one and 59 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,59}`
- [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\s|$)`

  - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\s`

    - [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `$`

    - [Assert position at the end of a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNFCB.png) `$`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)